# How do i get only the Json keys as a output from ADF lookup activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This is my json which read via a lookup activity

```
{
 "key1" : { "id" = "100" },
 "key2" : "XYZ",
 "key3" : [1,2,3]
}
```

I need a activity that gives me all the keys alone  from above json

```
Lookup.output.firstrow.key2 gives me the string XYZ
```

What expression i can use to get all the keys alone

I really looking for some expression like  Lookup.output.firstrow.getKeys() which returns array of keys such as
["key1", "key2", "key3"]

Comment: Hey,Do you have a SQL database in your system? you can use openjson query

Comment: I use Azure datafactory .  i have loaded the json via a lookup activity , now  looking for a expression to get the keys. There is no sql in my system

Comment: Are the number of keys fixed or would that vary?

Comment: The number of keys will vary

Answer (score 0):

> How do i get only the Json keys as a output from ADF lookup activity

There is no such direct way to achieve this you have to do it by setting the variables and string manipulation.

Follow below procedure:

1. I took json file in look up and its output is as follow:
   [image]
2. To get all keys from above Json first I took set variable activity and created a **demo** `string` variable with value.

```
@substring(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),2,sub(length(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)),4))
```

here we are converting lookup output to string and removing braces from start and end.

[image]

3. Then I took another set variable activity and created a **demo2** `array` variable with value.

```
@split(substring(string(split(variables('demo'),':')),2,sub(length(string(split(variables('demo'),':'))),4)),',')
```

Here we are splitting the string with `:` and `,`

[image]

4. Then I created an array with default range of even numbers of values 0,2,4,6 etc.
   [image]
5. Then Passed it to ForEach activity
   [image]
6. Then Inside For Each activity I took append variable activity and gave value as

```
@variables('demo2')[item()]
```

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

> **Note:** if your values contain `:` or  `,` the above expression will also split those values. and if we split the values with `:` then I will split the string with `:` only and rest thing it will consider as single value. In below image the highlighted value it is taking as single value.
> [image]